# Embedding multiple pages with same header in multiple <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to embed url `http://localhost:8081/static/bar.html` in the main `div` at my `index.html`, so I wrote the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Awesome echarts</title>
        <script src="https://go-echarts.github.io/go-echarts-assets/assets/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://go-echarts.github.io/go-echarts-assets/assets/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://localhost:8081/static/bar.html"></object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where my `bar.html` is:

```
<div class="select" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:10px; position:fixed; right:10px;"></div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item" id="eeUwxscJvXae"
         style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    var myChart_eeUwxscJvXae = echarts.init(document.getElementById('eeUwxscJvXae'), "white");
    var option_eeUwxscJvXae = {
        title: {"text":"Bar-示例图",},
        tooltip: {},
        legend: {},
        toolbox: {"show":true,"feature":{"saveAsImage":{},"dataZoom":{},"dataView":{},"restore":{}}},
        xAxis: [{"data":["衬衫","牛仔裤","运动裤","袜子","冲锋衣","羊毛衫"],"splitArea":{"show":false,},"splitLine":{"show":false,}}],
        yAxis: [{"axisLabel":{"show":true},"splitArea":{"show":false,},"splitLine":{"show":false,}}],
        series: [
        {"name":"商家A","type":"bar","data":[43,10,4,12,6,38],"label":{"show":false},"emphasis":{"label":{"show":false},},"markLine":{"label":{"show":false}},"markPoint":{"label":{"show":false}},},
        {"name":"商家B","type":"bar","data":[21,44,37,19,32,34],"label":{"show":false},"emphasis":{"label":{"show":false},},"markLine":{"label":{"show":false}},"markPoint":{"label":{"show":false}},},
        ],
        color: ["#c23531","#2f4554","#61a0a8","#d48265","#91c7ae","#749f83","#ca8622","#bda29a","#6e7074","#546570","#c4ccd3"],
    };
    myChart_eeUwxscJvXae.setOption(option_eeUwxscJvXae);
</script>

<style>
    .container {margin-top:30px; display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;}
    .item {margin: auto;}
</style>
```

But While loading it at the browser, I got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: echarts is not defined
    at bar.html:9
```

[image]

Why this is happening, is not it assumed that sub div are calling the header in the caller file?

I got it resolved by re-wriitng the header in the `bar.html` file, i.e.:

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://go-echarts.github.io/go-echarts-assets/assets/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://go-echarts.github.io/go-echarts-assets/assets/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

But is not this meaning double loading of the `echarts.min.js` and the `bulma.min.css` and what if I wanted to embed multiple pages like this, in multiple `div`s in the `index.html`  do I need to call these files for every single div?

Comment: `object` is not a `div`, it's another document with its own context - and this context doesn't have direct access to its parent `window` and variables defined there.

Comment: you shoule not be injecting javascipt like that. js must be initalised at the end of the page so that it waits for everything to load. now in your case you could create different js file for your logic and include it at the end of `index.html`

Comment: @raina77ow, thanks, mmm, what could be the alternate solution then,

Comment: @Harkal any sample code?

Comment: @HasanAYousef wait

Comment: @HasanAYousef sorry i got a bit busy. well as mentioned by `raina77ow` this object tag is used to inject external source files so there is no way any mother window thing can reach it. you ll hava to add those lines to every object  tag file you include in your index.html ;)

Comment: basically the object tag is not intended for what you are trying to do. you can use javascript to manuplate DOM if you want else i dont see any direct use of obect in your code you could just directly include the code in your index.html

Comment: if you still want your code to be in different files then i can give you some hint if you wanta

Comment: @Harkal the subcode is automatically generated from the server based on the user input, this is why it is dynamic, nit static to be hardcoded in the index.html

Comment: @HasanAYousef ok wait i m coming up with something

Comment: @Harkal, pls give your hints :)

Comment: @HasanAYousef please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that I just tested. It works fine, and will suffice for your purpose.

index.html

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div source="header.html"></div>
    <script>
        window.test = "this is a test";

        function includeSource() {
            var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
            /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
            z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
                elmnt = z[i];
                /*search for elements with a certain attribute:*/
                file = elmnt.getAttribute("source");
                if (file) {
                    /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4) {
                            if (this.status == 200) {
                                elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            // now we'll run the js if there is some direct js code in script tags
                            var html = document.createElement('html');
                            html.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            const scripts = html.getElementsByTagName("script");
                            for (const script of scripts) {
                                eval(script.innerText);
                            }
                            }
                            if (this.status == 404) {
                                elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";
                            }
                            /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
                            elmnt.removeAttribute("source");
                            includeSource();
                        }
                    }
                    xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
                    xhttp.send();
                    /*exit the function:*/
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
        includeSource();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

header.html

```
<style>
    .header {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: blueviolet;
    }
</style>

<div class="header">
    <span>Test</span>
    <button onclick="console.log(window.test)">click me</button>
</div>
<script>
    console.log(window.test);
</script>
```

Observe the `source` attribute on the div; it'll be used to define the path of the html file you want to load and you can include your JS and CSS in the same file.

Comment: Great, that, can you explain why to: `/*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/`

Comment: what if the header.html have another `source` attribute ? so that it loads more source code

Comment: @HasanAYousef please accept the answer i m need of reputation ;)

Comment: The `header.html` is working fine, but my script is not working without `elmnt.removeAttribute("source"); includeSource();` any thought?

Comment: you need to `removeAttribute` because the function has to run again and you dont want to load the content again and `includeSource` is running again beacause if the `header.html` have some more source attributes then it can load that as well. this is all i had in my mind while writing this thing

Comment: Actually it is working fine for the first element without `elmnt.removeAttribute("source"); includeSource();` if there is a second element, the `elmnt.removeAttribute("source"); includeSource();` are required, for the 3rd element, it is not working, trying to figure it out!

Comment: @HasanAYousef i leave it to you to discoveer that out ;) feeling sleepy. btw i loved the question. such questions are rarely seen on SO

Comment: Could not figure it yet!